# Sql exception was unhandled

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ado.net

I have this code in C# (Visual Studio 2012), it was retriving the data perfectly before now it randomly says 'Sql exception was unhandled' 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' 
It says it from the line that reads.... ads.Fill(dt)

This is my code....

```
SqlConnection ssl = new SqlConnection();
        ssl.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=Jhon;Initial Catalog=Training;Integrated Security=True";
        ssl.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter ads= new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT order, price, FROM table WHERE order < 100", ssl);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ads.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I can't ever express how much using Try/Catch blocks to trap and handle exceptions are useful, and save time.  Add a try/catch block around it, and msgbox the error result.

Comment: @Sanuel Jackson, while certainly exception handling has its place and should almost certainly be employed when performing something like data access, your suggestion doesn't help because the IDE already displays information for unhandled exceptions in the Exception Assistant window anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - i disagree.  coding, sure, you can skip lots of proper error trapping/handling, however end product should have as many as reasonably possible critical functions trapped and handled.  In this case, it is faster (both for troubleshooting, and end program), to handle exceptions as you go, rather than go back through the code after it is completed.

Comment: @SanuelJackson, I disagree with your disagreement.  I'm certainly not saying that exception handling should not be used in general or in this case but doing so in this case would not make solving the issue any easier.  The OP knows the error message and has access to all the exception data already.  If you display the error data in a message box then you will likely have to remove that before deployment or use conditional compilation.  What I would recommend is `Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` in every `catch` block, which will not affect the Release version.  No more OT stuff from me though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - it's actually better to write a global function and call that (in try/catch), which makes it one stop to change from live to debug -- can even set the code to do different things depending on if in IDE or if compiled .. which compile mode was used, etc. -- but your disagreement was essentially what I was stating in message 1 :) -- trap while coding.  after time, you learn to globalize the destination of the error into one function, then handle (silent, debug out, etc... dev choice really... main thing is to do it in the first place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong due to the comma after `price`. Change your query to `SELECT order, price FROM ...` to resolve the issue.

EDIT: As a general good practice, you should wrap this code in a try/catch block and properly handle the exceptions e.g. by logging to a file. Also, as another answer points out, you should avoid using reserved words for your own tables/columns, and if you do use them, you should escape them by putting them inside square brackets e.g. `[table]`

Comment: This is correct, however I still encourage Try/Catch  :)  ---  should have waited til the OP added that ^.^ --- just good coding form :)

Comment: @SanuelJackson I agree. Gonna edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I just made a small change to your answer ---  put the full query in `"SELECT order, price FROM table WHERE order < 100", ssl`

Comment: I have try/catch :) thanks for the help guys highly appreciated!

Comment: @user3517479 Glad to help! Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is your table really named "table"?  That seems a rather poor choice.  I would think that that would be a reserved word so would need to be escaped, i.e. `[table]`.  The best option is to not use reserved words as identifiers though.

Comment: No it's not I just didn't want to say the real table name :P